# Flutter Firebase Auth throws NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'data' was called on null

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

During the email app signup process using `firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword`, when I try to do an upload or save to prefs in the `.then` part it throws this error:
`NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'data' was called on null.`

So I can work around this by Navigating to a new screen and postponing processing of the user's TextFormField input till there, but it's messy and bugs me.

Doing anything big in the `.then` seems problematic but I don't really know what's causing the problem, or what in fact the best way is to solve this kind of issue for future clarity.  Education appreciated!

```
  void registerToFb() {
    firebaseAuth
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
            email: emailController.text, password: passwordController.text)
        .then((result) async {

      Person user = new Person();
      user.email = emailController.text;
      user.firstName = firstNameController.text;
      user.surname = surnameController.text;
      user.postcode = postcodeController.text;

      user.password = passwordController.text;

      user.city = cityController.text ?? "Edinburgh";
      user.firebaseId = result.user.uid;

      Map<String, dynamic> firebaseUpload = user.toMap();
      print("Attempting to reduce upload");
      firebaseUpload.removeWhere((key, value) => value == null);

      user.country = "GB";

      String path = "${user.country}/${user.city}/People";
      print("Attempting record upload");
      DocumentReference autoId =
          await myFirestore.collection(path).add(firebaseUpload);
      user.personId = autoId.id;

      user.saveToPrefs(prefs);

      Navigator.pushReplacement(
          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyHomePage()));

    }).catchError((err) {
      print("Login thrown an error...\n${err.toString()}");
      showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return AlertDialog(
              title: Text("Error 10"),
              content: Text("${err.toString()}"),
              actions: [
                ElevatedButton(
                  child: Text("Ok"),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  },
                )
              ],
            );
          });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A suggestion from me is to completely remove the **.then()** callback, since you have it stated as *async*. A better approach would be to make the whole function async, so you can do all your async code directly inside that.

1. Make the function async

```
void registerToFb() async { ...
```

2. Change the .then() callback to a simple await and store the result in your result variable.

```
var result = await firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: emailController.text, password: passwordController.text);
```

3. I would highly suggest surrounding this statement with a try/catch block, to avoid unhandled errors:

```
try {
  var result = await firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
    email: emailController.text,
    password: passowrdController.text
  );
} on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
  if (e.code == 'weak-password') {
    print('password too weak.');
  } else if (e.code == 'email-already-in-use') {
    print('email already exists');
  }
} catch (e) {
  print(e);
}
```

4. You might get this error because you marked the .then() call as async, since it then executes asynchronously and the data might not be "there" yet, but I am not sure about this one.

Comment: Cheers for the thoughtful answer.  It solved it, turns out that when turning my user Person object into a map for Firebase upload there was a bug.  This bug wasn't flagged in logs till I did as you said, Async-ed the whole function & eliminated the .then.  Next issue now, hurrah @Irsvmb!